# Represent a tridiagonal sparse matrix in column major order

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix

Main Question:-
If the elements in the band formed by the three diagonals of a tridiagonal matrix X are represented column-wise in an array Y, with X[1,1] being stored in Y[1], then write an algorithm to determine the value of X[i, j], 1 <= i, j <= n from array Y.

I did some calculation in rough and found the size of 1D array required and index to row and column index for main diagonal and upper diagonal but failing to do so for lower diagonal

CONSIDERING A  MATRIX WITH 5 ROWS AND 5 COLUMNS

```
|A11 A12  0   0   0 |
|A21 A22 A23  0   0 |
| 0  A32 A33 A34  0 |
| 0   0  A43 A44 A45|
| 0   0   0  A54 A55|
```

Size of the array (3*n - 2),

```
here size of the array = (3*5 - 2) = 13

 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
A11 A21 A12 A22 A32 A23 A33 A43 A34 A44 A54 A45 A55 

i=row index, 1<=i<=N
j=column index, 1<=j<=N
k=array index
```

Now for main diagonal

```
i j k
1 1 0
2 2 3
3 3 6
4 4 9
5 5 12
I got the relation as 3i - 3
```

For Upper diagonal

```
i j k
1 2 2
2 3 5
3 4 8
4 5 11
I got the relation as 4i - j
```

Now for lower diagonal(question)

```
i j k
2 1 1
3 2 4
4 3 7
5 4 10
Relation ??
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I cannot find the relation between array index k and row index i and column index j for the matrix for lower diagonal like for main diagonal its 3i-3 and for upper diagonal is 4i-j

Comment: It would be much better if you replaced the diagrams with text in the question.  You would format the notes as 'code' by indenting or by surrounding it with two lines containing just three back-ticks `\`\`\`` (or, better, by `\`\`\`none` before and `\`\`\`` after).

Comment: tried adding the problem as text

Answer (score 3):

## Summary

You'll find that (indexing from 1), for an NxN tridiagonal matrix X
linearized in column-major order into an array Z, the entry in row r:

- On the main diagonal of X is at index (3 * c - 2) of Y for c = 1..N;
- On the upper-diagonal of X is at (3 * c - 3) of Y (for c = 1..N-1);
- On the lower-diagonal of X is at (3 * c - 1) of Y (for c = 2..N).

For an element with row r, column c (both in the range 1..N):

- if |r - c| > 1 then the value is zero;
- if c == r then it is on the leading diagonal;
- if c = r + 1 then it is on the upper diagonal;
- if c = r - 1 then it is on the lower diagonal.

Of course, in C, arrays are indexed from zero, not one.

## Cogitations

- NxN tri-diagonal matrix X
- Linearized in row-major order into array Y with `3*N-2` entries
- Linearized in column-major order into array Z with `3*N-2` entries
- Non-zero elements have c = r + { -1, 0, +1 }
- Equivalently they have r = c + { -1, 0, +1 }
- With one-based indexing, the first row with an element on the lower
  diagonal is r = 2 and the last row with an element on the upper
  diagonal is r = N - 1.
- With zero-based indexing, the first row with an element on the lower
  diagonal is r = 1 and the last rows with an element on the upper
  diagonal is r = N - 2.
- In the linearized vectors, the notation is:

  - D = diagonal, L = lower diagonal, U = upper diagonal

### Row-Major Order with Zero-Based Indexing

```
X   c = 0   1   2   3   4   5
      +----------------------
r = 0 | 1   2   0   0   0   0
r = 1 | 3   4   5   0   0   0
r = 2 | 0   6   7   8   0   0
r = 3 | 0   0   9  10  11   0
r = 4 | 0   0   0  12  13  14
r = 5 | 0   0   0   0  15  16

       D  U  L  D  U  L  D  U  L  D  U  L  D  U  L D
Y = {  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 }
Index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

- Elements on main  diagonal at indexes: 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15
- Elements on upper diagonal at indexes: 1, 4, 7, 10, 13
- Elements on lower diagonal at indexes: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14

Function `get_rm_0()`:

- `X[r,c] = 0         if |r - c| > 1`
- `X[r,c] = 3 * r + 0 if r == c + 0` — Main diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * r + 1 if r == c - 1` — Upper diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * r - 1 if r == c + 1` — Lower diagonal

Always subject to 0 <= r < N; 0 <= c < N

### Row-Major Order with One-Based Indexing

```
X   c = 1   2   3   4   5   6
      +----------------------
r = 1 | 1   2   0   0   0   0
r = 2 | 3   4   5   0   0   0
r = 3 | 0   6   7   8   0   0
r = 4 | 0   0   9  10  11   0
r = 5 | 0   0   0  12  13  14
r = 6 | 0   0   0   0  15  16

       D  U  L  D  U  L  D  U  L  D  U  L  D  U  L D
Y = {  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 }
Index  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

- Elements on main  diagonal at indexes: 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16
- Elements on upper diagonal at indexes: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14
- Elements on lower diagonal at indexes: 3, 6, 9, 12, 15

Function `get_rm_1()`:

- `X[r,c] = 0         if |r - c| > 1`
- `X[r,c] = 3 * r - 2 if r == c + 0` — Main diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * r - 1 if r == c - 1` — Upper diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * r - 3 if r == c + 1` — Lower diagonal

Always subject to 0 < r <= N; 0 <= c <= N

## Column-major instead of row-major order

> You are correct.  Here you are considering row-major order.  I
> wanted to store the elements in the array as:
>
> Z = { 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12, 11, 13, 15, 14, 16 }
>
> as per your example

### Column-Major Order with One-Based Indexing

So, you can make a parallel argument to the one I gave.  Annotate
your column-major array Z similarly to the way I annotated the
row-major array Y:

```
       D   L   U   D   L   U   D   L   U   D   L   U   D   L   U   D
Z = {  1,  3,  2,  4,  6,  5,  7,  9,  8, 10, 12, 11, 13, 15, 14, 16 }
Index  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
```

- Elements on main  diagonal at indexes: 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16
- Elements on upper diagonal at indexes: 3, 6, 9, 12, 15
- Elements on lower diagonal at indexes: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14

Function `get_cm_1()`:

- `X[r,c] = 0         if |c - r| > 1`
- `X[r,c] = 3 * c - 2 if c == r + 0` — Main diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * c - 3 if c == r + 1` — Upper diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * c - 1 if c == r - 1` — Lower diagonal

Always subject to 0 < r <= N; 0 < c <= N.

### Column-Major Order with Zero-Based Indexing

```
       D   L   U   D   L   U   D   L   U   D   L   U   D   L   U   D
Z = {  1,  3,  2,  4,  6,  5,  7,  9,  8, 10, 12, 11, 13, 15, 14, 16 }
Index  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
```

- Elements on main  diagonal at indexes:  0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15
- Elements on upper diagonal at indexes:  2,  5,  8, 11, 14
- Elements on lower diagonal at indexes:  1,  4,  7, 10, 13

Function `get_cm_0()`:

- `X[r,c] = 0         if |c - r| > 1`
- `X[r,c] = 3 * c + 0 if c == r + 0` — Main diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * c - 1 if c == r + 1` — Upper diagonal
- `X[r,c] = 3 * c + 1 if c == r - 1` — Lower diagonal

Always subject to 0 <= r < N; 0 <= c < N.

## Code

Source file `td59.c`:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { N = 6 };

static const int X[N][N] =
{
    {  1,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  3,  4,  5,  0,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  6,  7,  8,  0,  0 },
    {  0,  0,  9, 10, 11,  0 },
    {  0,  0,  0, 12, 13, 14 },
    {  0,  0,  0,  0, 15, 16 },
};

static const int Y[3*N-2] =
{
    1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,
    9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
};

static const int Z[3*N-2] =
{
     1,  3,  2,  4,  6,  5,  7,  9,
     8, 10, 12, 11, 13, 15, 14, 16,
};

/* rm = row major, cm = column major, 0 = zero-based, 1 = one-based */

static int get_rm_0(int r, int c)
{
    assert(r >= 0 && r < N);
    assert(c >= 0 && c < N);
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d\n", __func__, r, c);
    if (abs(r - c) > 1)         /* Off tridiagonal */
        return 0;
    int index;
    if (r == c)                 /* Main diagonal */
        index = 3 * r + 0;
    else if (r == c - 1)        /* Upper diagonal */
        index = 3 * r + 1;
    else
    {
        assert(r == c + 1);
        index = 3 * r - 1;      /* Lower diagonal */
    }
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d, i = %d, v = %d\n", __func__, r, c, index, Y[index]);
    return Y[index];
}

static int get_rm_1(int r, int c)
{
    assert(r > 0 && r <= N);
    assert(c > 0 && c <= N);
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d\n", __func__, r, c);
    if (abs(r - c) > 1)         /* Off tridiagonal */
        return 0;
    int index;
    if (r == c)                 /* Main diagonal */
        index = 3 * r - 2;
    else if (r == c - 1)        /* Upper diagonal */
        index = 3 * r - 1;
    else
    {
        assert(r == c + 1);
        index = 3 * r - 3;      /* Lower diagonal */
    }
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d, i = %d, v = %d\n", __func__, r, c, index, Y[index-1]);
    return Y[index-1];
}

static int get_cm_0(int r, int c)
{
    assert(r >= 0 && r < N);
    assert(c >= 0 && c < N);
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d\n", __func__, r, c);
    if (abs(r - c) > 1)         /* Off tridiagonal */
        return 0;
    int index;
    if (c == r)                 /* Main diagonal */
        index = 3 * c + 0;
    else if (c == r + 1)        /* Upper diagonal */
        index = 3 * c - 1;
    else
    {
        assert(c == r - 1);
        index = 3 * c + 1;      /* Lower diagonal */
    }
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d, i = %d, v = %d\n", __func__, r, c, index, Z[index]);
    return Z[index];
}

static int get_cm_1(int r, int c)
{
    assert(r > 0 && r <= N);
    assert(c > 0 && c <= N);
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d\n", __func__, r, c);
    if (abs(r - c) > 1)         /* Off tridiagonal */
        return 0;
    int index;
    if (c == r)                 /* Main diagonal */
        index = 3 * c - 2;
    else if (c == r + 1)        /* Upper diagonal */
        index = 3 * c - 3;
    else
    {
        assert(c == r - 1);
        index = 3 * c - 1;      /* Lower diagonal */
    }
    //printf("%s(): r = %d, c = %d, i = %d, v = %d\n", __func__, r, c, index, Z[index-1]);
    return Z[index-1];
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols,
        const int matrix[rows][cols], int base)
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d) %d-based:\n", tag, rows, cols, base);
    printf("     c =");
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        printf("  %2d", c + base);
    putchar('\n');
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        printf("r = %d: {", r + base);
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            printf("  %2d", matrix[r][c]);
        puts(" }");
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

static void dump_vector(const char *tag, int values, const int vector[values], int base)
{
    printf("Vector %s (%d) %d-based:\n", tag, values, base);
    int len = 0;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < values; i++)
    {
        len += printf("%s[%2d] = %2d,", pad, i + base, vector[i]);
        pad = " ";
        if (len > 80)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            len = 0;
            pad = "";
        }
    }
    if (len > 0)
        putchar('\n');
    putchar('\n');
}

static void reconstruct_matrix(const char *matrix_tag, const char *vector_tag,
        int values, const int vector[values],
        int rows, int cols, int (*getter)(int r, int c), int base)
{
    dump_vector(vector_tag, values, vector, base);
    printf("%s (%dx%d) %d-based:\n", matrix_tag, rows, cols, base);
    for (int r = 0 + base; r < rows + base; r++)
    {
        printf("r = %d: {", r);
        for (int c = 0 + base; c < cols + base; c++)
            printf("  %2d", (*getter)(r, c));
        puts(" }");
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    dump_matrix("Tridiagonal matrix X", N, N, X, 0);
    reconstruct_matrix("Reconstructed Row-Major Matrix", "Y", 3 * N - 2, Y, N, N, get_rm_0, 0);

    dump_matrix("Tridiagonal matrix X", N, N, X, 1);
    reconstruct_matrix("Reconstructed Row-Major Matrix", "Y", 3 * N - 2, Y, N, N, get_rm_1, 1);

    puts("\n\n");

    dump_matrix("Tridiagonal matrix X", N, N, X, 0);
    reconstruct_matrix("Reconstructed Column-Major Matrix", "Z", 3 * N - 2, Z, N, N, get_cm_0, 0);
    dump_matrix("Tridiagonal matrix X", N, N, X, 1);
    reconstruct_matrix("Reconstructed Column-Major Matrix", "Z", 3 * N - 2, Z, N, N, get_cm_1, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

There are many possible changes that could be made to this code.

- Use functions `get_[cr]m_[01]_idx()` to get the array index in the vector.  They would return `-1` when the cell is off the tri-diagonal.
- Use a modified vector (`Y`, `Z`) which has an extra element with value `0` at the start.  Use `const int *Y1 = &Y[1];` and then you can use: `int val = Y1[get_rm_1_idx(r, c)];` to get the value.
- Revise the `get_[cr]m_[01]()` functions to take the vector instead of using global variables `Y` and `Z`.
- Rename the functions `get_[cr]m_[01]()` functions using `get_[cr]m_[01]_val()` to indicate that they get the value.
- Add printing to report the index into the vectors `Y` and `Z` at which the value is found.

## Output

```
Tridiagonal matrix X (6x6) 0-based:
     c =   0   1   2   3   4   5
r = 0: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 1: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }

Vector Y (16) 0-based:
[ 0] =  1, [ 1] =  2, [ 2] =  3, [ 3] =  4, [ 4] =  5, [ 5] =  6, [ 6] =  7, [ 7] =  8,
[ 8] =  9, [ 9] = 10, [10] = 11, [11] = 12, [12] = 13, [13] = 14, [14] = 15, [15] = 16,

Reconstructed Row-Major Matrix (6x6) 0-based:
r = 0: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 1: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }

Tridiagonal matrix X (6x6) 1-based:
     c =   1   2   3   4   5   6
r = 1: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 6: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }

Vector Y (16) 1-based:
[ 1] =  1, [ 2] =  2, [ 3] =  3, [ 4] =  4, [ 5] =  5, [ 6] =  6, [ 7] =  7, [ 8] =  8,
[ 9] =  9, [10] = 10, [11] = 11, [12] = 12, [13] = 13, [14] = 14, [15] = 15, [16] = 16,

Reconstructed Row-Major Matrix (6x6) 1-based:
r = 1: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 6: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }

Tridiagonal matrix X (6x6) 0-based:
     c =   0   1   2   3   4   5
r = 0: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 1: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }

Vector Z (16) 0-based:
[ 0] =  1, [ 1] =  3, [ 2] =  2, [ 3] =  4, [ 4] =  6, [ 5] =  5, [ 6] =  7, [ 7] =  9,
[ 8] =  8, [ 9] = 10, [10] = 12, [11] = 11, [12] = 13, [13] = 15, [14] = 14, [15] = 16,

Reconstructed Column-Major Matrix (6x6) 0-based:
r = 0: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 1: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }

Tridiagonal matrix X (6x6) 1-based:
     c =   1   2   3   4   5   6
r = 1: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 6: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }

Vector Z (16) 1-based:
[ 1] =  1, [ 2] =  3, [ 3] =  2, [ 4] =  4, [ 5] =  6, [ 6] =  5, [ 7] =  7, [ 8] =  9,
[ 9] =  8, [10] = 10, [11] = 12, [12] = 11, [13] = 13, [14] = 15, [15] = 14, [16] = 16,

Reconstructed Column-Major Matrix (6x6) 1-based:
r = 1: {   1   2   0   0   0   0 }
r = 2: {   3   4   5   0   0   0 }
r = 3: {   0   6   7   8   0   0 }
r = 4: {   0   0   9  10  11   0 }
r = 5: {   0   0   0  12  13  14 }
r = 6: {   0   0   0   0  15  16 }
```

Comment: Awesome You are correct here you are considering row major order. I wanted to store the elements in the array as {1,3,2,4,6,5,7,9.8,10,12,11,13,15,14,16}  as per your example hope u understood

Comment: I had also tried this for Row major order main diagonal (array index = n-1+i-1) again for lower diagonal (array index = i-2) and for upper diagonal (array index = 2*n-1+i-1) here I am indexing matrix from 1

Comment: See the update — I applied the same general technique I demonstrated with row-major order to sort out column-major order.

Comment: For some values the relation is not working

Comment: ya its more fiddly, I accept it. Tried all sort of random combinations in this. I am also on it

Comment: Do check I have added all the details and my approach in the question itself

Comment: @hamzahasan — I've updated (rewritten) my answer.  It includes code which demonstrates to my satisfaction that it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `d` is the main diagonal, `a` is the "above" diagonal, and `b` is the "below" diagonal:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| d | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| b | d | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | b | d | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | b | d | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | b | d | a | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | b | d | a | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | b | d | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | b | d |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Note that the problem assumes indexes are "origin 1" (e.g. `1 <= i <= n`) but C arrays want "origin 0" (e.g. `0 <= i < n`)

---

We can use an "inner" struct to represent the Y array (e.g. `elem_t`) and the basic functions are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// sparse matrix Y vector
typedef struct {
    int a;                          // above diagonal
    int d;                          // main diagonal
    int b;                          // below diagonal
} elem_t;

// sparse matrix
typedef struct {
    int n;
    elem_t *base;
} sparse_t;

// sparse_create -- create sparse tridiagonal matrix
sparse_t *
sparse_create(int n)
{
    sparse_t *mtx = malloc(sizeof(*mtx));

    mtx->n = n;
    mtx->base = calloc(n,sizeof(*mtx->base));

    return mtx;
}

// sparse_pointer -- point to sparse matrix element
int *
sparse_pointer(sparse_t *mtx,int coli,int rowi)
{
    int n = mtx->n;
    elem_t *eptr;
    int *iptr = NULL;

    // convert to origin 0
    coli -= 1;
    rowi -= 1;

    do {
        // check column bounds
        if (coli < 0)
            break;
        if (coli >= n)
            break;

        // check row bounds
        if (rowi < 0)
            break;
        if (rowi >= n)
            break;

        eptr = &mtx->base[coli];

        // main diagonal
        if (rowi == coli) {
            iptr = &eptr->d;
            break;
        }

        // above diagnonal
        if ((rowi == (coli - 1)) && (coli > 0)) {
            iptr = &eptr->a;
            break;
        }

        // below diagnonal
        if ((rowi == (coli + 1)) && (coli < (n - 1))) {
            iptr = &eptr->b;
            break;
        }
    } while (0);

    return iptr;
}

// sparse_getval -- get matrix value
int
sparse_getval(sparse_t *mtx,int coli,int rowi)
{
    int *iptr = sparse_pointer(mtx,coli,rowi);
    int val;

    if (iptr != NULL)
        val = *iptr;
    else
        val = 0;

    return val;
}

// sparse_setval -- set matrix value
void
sparse_setval(sparse_t *mtx,int coli,int rowi,int val)
{
    int *iptr = sparse_pointer(mtx,coli,rowi);

    if (iptr != NULL)
        *iptr = val;
}
```

---

By contrast, a regular/full matrix would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// regular/full matrix
typedef struct {
    int n;
    int *base;
} regmtx_t;

// regmtx_create -- create regular matrix
regmtx_t *
regmtx_create(int n)
{
    regmtx_t *mtx = malloc(sizeof(*mtx));

    mtx->n = n;
    mtx->base = calloc(n * n,sizeof(*mtx->base));

    return mtx;
}

// regmtx_pointer -- point to regular matrix element
int *
regmtx_pointer(regmtx_t *mtx,int coli,int rowi)
{
    int *iptr = NULL;

    // convert to origin 0
    coli -= 1;
    rowi -= 1;

    do {
        // check column bounds
        if (coli < 0)
            break;
        if (coli >= mtx->n)
            break;

        // check row bounds
        if (rowi < 0)
            break;
        if (rowi >= mtx->n)
            break;

        iptr = &mtx->base[(coli * mtx->n) + rowi];
    } while (0);

    return iptr;
}
```

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, if there's a request for one of the zero elements of the matrix, you return a null pointer rather than a pointer to a zero.  Are you sure that's appropriate?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The `sparse_pointer` is a "base" function. What I didn't show was the "outer" functions `sparse_getval` (which returns 0 if the pointer is null) and `sparse_setval` that simply doesn't set the value if the pointer is null.